# Hamming weight probability of projections

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, coding-theory, measure-concentration

Given $s,t\in(0,1)$, $c>1$, $n\in\Bbb N$, pick $2^{n^t}$ random vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{n^t}}$ such that each $v_i\in\{x\in\{0,1\}^{2^n}:|x|_{hamming}={2^{n-n^s}}\}$.

If $v_i^\perp$ is projection of first $2^{n/c}$ coordinates of each $v_i$, then is the probability that there is a vector $v$ in $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{n^t}}$ such that $|v_i^\perp|_{hamming}<2^{n/cd}$ holds with some real $d>1$ close to $1$ or close to $0$?

Comment: What's the role of $s$? The $s$ takes no part in your proposed answer and may not matter much.

Comment: This means that even at $s,t\rightarrow0$ a solution exists.

Comment: Shouldn't the distribution of the first $v=2^{n/c}$ coordinates be approximately (one should actually do sampling without replacement) drawn from $Bin(2^{-n^s}, v)$? Your first sum then would possibly need to be adjusted.